# UITextView Border on three sides

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently styling a UITextView so that it looks like a text field using the following code:

```
//To make the border look very close to a UITextField
[_smsMessage.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
[_smsMessage.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];

//The rounded corner part
_smsMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_smsMessage.clipsToBounds = YES;

// Make append text view match
[_smsAppend.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
[_smsAppend.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];

//The rounded corner part
_smsAppend.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_smsAppend.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

It puts a thin boarder around and then rounds the edges.

But what I would like to do is have this border for all sides apart from the bottom (so it would be the left, top and right sides that have the boarder, leaving the bottom exposed).

I'm unsure on how to implement this, does anyone have any ideas? - I have tried to research online, but I think the benefit of experience will come into play in this one.

I think that I will have to use some kind of sub-view (or a set of sub-views), can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in support for this.

You could create a CAShapeLayer that's the same size as your view, and then add a CGPath to the layer. The path would be a combination of line segments and arc segments. If you look up how you construct a rounded rectangle you'll find an explanation of how to build one from line segments are arcs.

You could then add the the shape layer as a sub-layer of your view's content layer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fiddling around with borders, create a 9 segment image and set it as the background.

Comment: I did think about doing this, but i'd like to keep the amount of 'formatting images' down, I was hoping the solution to do it within code wouldn't be too long.. But it looks like sub-views are the only way.

Comment: what is the reason for wanting to avoid using images?

Comment: I've just already got a lot of images that are used for specific things and I would rather do it programatically, as i'm trying to learn objective-c in the process. I know using images would work, but to me it's kind of cheating. 

But if it turns out to be overly complex, i'll just use images.

Comment: images are actually more efficient, since they just need blitting, while drawing via code uses the CPU. but if want to do it in code, implement -[UIView drawInRect:] for a custom background view, and possibly use http://www.paintcodeapp.com for design as it generates drawing code graphically.

Comment: Ooh that's interesting, thank you! I had heard of paintcode, but haven't tried it, i'll download it and give it a go.